# same code, different browser, different behaviour for cookieset()

Tags: php, cookies, browser

I was learnig how to make a cookie in php, and as first example i wanted to do a visit counter. This works on chrome but not in mozilla. What i have to change in order to make the code works on every browser?
Thank y ou for any help.

```
<?php
  if(!isset($_COOKIE["counter"])) {
    setcookie("counter",0,time()+3600,"/");
    $var = $_COOKIE["couter"];
  } else {
    $var = $_COOKIE["counter"] + 1;
    setcookie("counter",$var,time()+3600,"/");
  }
  echo $var;
 ?>
```

Comment: Client can reject a cookie, so there's probably nothing you can do if they don't want your sweeties ;)

Comment: aahhahah my sweeties are so good :((((('''''